# "! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode." Error

Tags: errors

I am using TEX editor and have written the following code:

```
\documentclass[10  pt,a4paper,twoside,reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsmath,enumerate,verbatim,calc} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\textwidth = 12.5 cm 
\textheight = 20 cm 
\topmargin = 0.5 cm 
\oddsidemargin = 1 cm 
\evensidemargin = 1 cm 
\pagestyle{plain} 
\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{July 25, 2015}
\maketitle
\abstract{Some text....
......................}
\section{Introduction}
Some text.....
.............

\end{document}
```

When I click "Quick Build" I get the following error **! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.** on Line 27 (Line containing \end{document}). Please explain why does this error occur and how should I got about fixing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `abstract` for an `amsart` document should be given in environment for

```
\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
```

Given as just `\abstract`, TeX is collecting a box, and you can't end the run the document in that situation. As there's no `\end{abstract}` you never close the box properly.

Answer (score 1):

The same error occurs if you by accident delete or forget to close a curly bracket

```
}
```

Such as in this example

```
\begin{table}
…
\label{This is a caption after which you forgot to close the bracket, exactly here -->
\end{table}
```

Comment: This code produces the error `Paragraph ended before \label was complete.` That's not the same as `You can't use \end in internal vertical mode.`

Comment: In my case it did produce the error "You can't use \end in internal vertical mode." That's why I ended up here in the first place.