# Fatal error occured, no output PDF file produced

Tags: errors, pdf, thesis

I was writing my bachelor-thesis as suddenly the message above came up. I already tried deleting the ouput files, with no impact.

Here is my ouput file for further information.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Coy8q8hperCG4eaaiYLNIxWtSXuSao81/view?usp=sharing

I'm a newbie to Latex, so please let me know if I should present any further information.

I recently used "\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}" to add a table, maybe this information is relevant regarding to the first answer.

I already want to thank you for the fast replies.

This is my preamble as u asked for, i hope it's not too much.

```
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ License ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Präambel ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %

% Artikel-Klasse mit a4paper Option für die Seitenränder
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Erweiterungen Torbjörn
%Zeilenabstand wie bei Word-Vorlage
\usepackage{setspace}
%Farben für Tabellen
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}


% Deutsch: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/German
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Anführungszeichen unten: "`
% Anführungszeichen oben: "'
\usepackage{csquotes}

% um Grafiken einzubinden, {Angabe des Pfades der Bilder}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

% zur korrekten Platzierung der Banner im Titelblatt
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}

% Zur Anpassung der Seitenränder
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

% Automatisches Generieren von Hyperlinks bei Verweisen und URLs
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true,     % Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = black,    % Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = black,    % Colour of internal links
  citecolor    = black     % Colour of citations
}

% sodass LoT, LoF und Literatur in ToC erscheint
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

% Listingverzeichnis
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listingverzeichnis}

% LoT und LoF nur ausgeben, wenn es Einträge gibt
% Mit diesem Packet werden alle vorhandenen Grafiken, Tabellen und Listings gezählt
\usepackage[figure,table,lstlisting]{totalcount}

% Akronyme mit Einstellungen bezüglich Gestaltung des Verzeichnisses
\usepackage[acronym, nogroupskip, nonumberlist, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{environment/acronym}
\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

% Biblatex als Literaturverwaltung
% Siehe auch die Datei biblatex.cfg
% Dokumentation: https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,     % ext- ermöglicht das Einblenden der Klammern um die Jahreszahl in Fußnoten
            sorting=nyt,              % Nach Nachnamen des ersten genannten Autorens sortieren, dann Jahr, dann Titel
            isbn=false,               % Ausblenden des Feldes
            url=false,                % Ausblenden des Feldes
            doi=false,                % Ausblenden des Feldes
            eprint=false,             % Ausblenden des Feldes
            maxcitenames=2,           % Ab drei Autoren mit "et at." abkürzen
            maxbibnames=100]{biblatex}% Alle Autoren im Literaturverzeichnis ausschreiben

% Einbinden der Literatureinträge
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% Zeilenumbrüche in Url bei jedem beliebigen Buchstaben,
% um overfull H-Boxes im Literaturverzeichnis zu vermeiden
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{1000}


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Konfiguration ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %

% Projektspezifische Einstellungen laden
% In dieser Datei müssen lediglich die vorgegebenen Variablen geändert werden
\input{environment/config.tex}

% Ob "Abb.", "Tbl." und "Lst." vor den Nummern der Verzeichnisse erscheinen
\ifdefined\varShowTitlesInLists
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\l@figure}[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{Abb. \sffamily#1}{\sffamily#2}}
  \renewcommand{\l@table}[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{Tbl. \sffamily#1}{\sffamily#2}}
  \renewcommand{\l@lstlisting}[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{Lst. \sffamily#1}{\sffamily#2}}
  \makeatother
\fi

% Ausblenden der Klammern um die Jahresangabe im Literaturverzeichnis
\ifdefined\varNoParenthesesAroundYear
  \makeatletter
  \def\act@on@bibmacro#1#2{%
    \expandafter#1\csname abx@macro@\detokenize{#2}\endcsname
  }
  \def\patchbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\patchcmd}
  \def\pretobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\pretocmd}
  \def\apptobibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\apptocmd}
  \def\showbibmacro{\act@on@bibmacro\show}
  \makeatother

  \patchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
  }{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
  }{}{}
\fi


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Dokument ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %

\begin{document}


  % Titelblatt
  \input{\varTitlepage}
  \newpage

  % Seitenzahlen auf große römische Zahlen umstellen
  \pagenumbering{Roman}

  % Inhaltsverzeichnis
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage

  % Abbildungsverzeichnis
  \iftotalfigures
    \listoffigures
  \fi

  % Tabellenverzeichnis
  \iftotaltables
    \listoftables
  \fi

  % Listingverzeichnis
  \iftotallstlistings
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listingverzeichnis}
    \lstlistoflistings
  \fi

  % Abkürzungsverzeichnis
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
  \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,sort=letter,style=listdotted,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
  \newpage

  % Arabische Seitennummerierung für den Hauptteil
  \pagenumbering{arabic}

  %Zeilenabstand
  \setstretch{1.2}

  % Inhalt der Arbeit -> Strukturierung in section/root
    \input{sections/root}
  \newpage

  % Literaturverzeichnis
  \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
  \newpage

  % Persönliche Erklärung
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \input{environment/pers_erklaerung}

\end{document}
```

Is it helpful?

Kind regards

Comment: Could it be something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331162/you-cant-use-end-in-internal-vertical-mode-error ?     You didn't produce an example (preferably a minimal working example), so there is no way for us to help you out beyond that.

Comment: Two of the error messages is about `\rowcolor` not being defined. This suggests that your document failed to load the `colortbl` package wasn't loaded. Another error message indicates that no suitable `\end{table}` instruction was found. Since you haven't posted even the preamble of your document, it's not possible to draw any further inferences at this time.

Comment: you posted some code but it does not allow anyone to see the error as we can not run it: `\input{sections/root}`  means it relies on files not provided. Try to make a small self contained file that shows the error. Also when asking about an error it helps if you show the error message